# Creating an instance of a generic type in DART

Tags: dart

I was wondering if is possible to create an instance of a generic type in Dart. In other languages like Java you could work around this using reflection, but I'm not sure if this is possible in Dart.

I have this class:

```dart
class GenericController <T extends RequestHandler> {

    void processRequest() {
        T t = new T();  // ERROR
    }
}
```

Comment: Type parameters in Dart implements the interface `Type`. The `Type` interface does not declares any members. This means that the interface `Type` used only as the identity key of runtime types. The reflection procedures built into Dart SDK but they are not a part of Dart core. This means that if you want to introspect your program you should use reflection library. Bridge between your program (at runtime) and reflection library are  the interface `Type`. You request (reflect) required information about the classes using this interface.

Comment: See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/12921

Comment: Not exact solution but, this may work for you;

void processRequest(T t) {
      t.something();
}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use similar code:

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

void main() {
  var controller = new GenericController<Foo>();
  controller.processRequest();
}

class GenericController<T extends RequestHandler> {
  void processRequest() {
    //T t = new T();
    T t = Activator.createInstance(T);
    t.tellAboutHimself();
  }
}

class Foo extends RequestHandler {
  void tellAboutHimself() {
    print("Hello, I am 'Foo'");
  }
}

abstract class RequestHandler {
  void tellAboutHimself();
}

class Activator {
  static createInstance(Type type, [Symbol constructor, List
      arguments, Map<Symbol, dynamic> namedArguments]) {
    if (type == null) {
      throw new ArgumentError("type: $type");
    }

    if (constructor == null) {
      constructor = const Symbol("");
    }

    if (arguments == null) {
      arguments = const [];
    }

    var typeMirror = reflectType(type);
    if (typeMirror is ClassMirror) {
      return typeMirror.newInstance(constructor, arguments, 
        namedArguments).reflectee;
    } else {
      throw new ArgumentError("Cannot create the instance of the type '$type'.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't work with flutter yet. +1 for Patrik's approach below.

Answer (score 105):

I tried mezonis approach with the Activator and it works. But it is an expensive approach as it uses mirrors, which requires you to use "mirrorsUsed" if you don't want to have a 2-4MB js file.

This morning I had the idea to use a generic typedef as generator and thus get rid of reflection:

You define a method type like this: (Add params if necessary)

```dart
typedef S ItemCreator<S>();
```

or even better:

```dart
typedef ItemCreator<S> = S Function();
```

Then in the class that needs to create the new instances:

```dart
class PagedListData<T>{
  ...
  ItemCreator<T> creator;
  PagedListData(ItemCreator<T> this.creator) {

  }

  void performMagic() {
      T item = creator();
      ... 
  }
}
```

Then you can instantiate the `PagedList` like this:

```dart
PagedListData<UserListItem> users 
         = new PagedListData<UserListItem>(()=> new UserListItem());
```

You don't lose the advantage of using generic because at declaration time you need to provide the target class anyway, so defining the creator method doesn't hurt.

Comment: Works with flutter

Comment: it totally worked for me. But I don't understand how `creator()` is creating an instance of `T` and not an instance of `ItemCreator<T>`. Can you explain that for me?

Comment: ItemCreator<T> is a function type of a function that returns something of type T, as you can see in the typedef. In the last code snippet you can see that the PagedListData instance is created and an instance of the creator function is provided. This is just a template and not a function call. This function is only called in the middle code snippet at "creator()". Does that help?

Comment: There really is no magic here. It boils down to delegating the instantiation responsibility to the consumer, via a callback. It's not a bad solution, but it would have been nice to be able to dynamically instantiate a type inside `PagedListData` without it. But I don't think it's possible without mirrors, which we don't have in Flutter.

Comment: As a matter of taste you might want your PagedListData and creator() declared abstract so that they are implemented on the sub-class level rather than by client.

Comment: It is now recommended to prefer this syntax for using typedef with generic types: `typedef ItemCreator<S> = S Function();`. This is because other syntax does not work with generics. Your example may look like the typedef preserves the type, but inside a function `ItemCreator<T>` is actually dynamic

Comment: This approach works well, but still relies on you bringing your own constructor. Ideally the extra boiler plate would all go inside the class definition, as normally expected with generics in other languages. It's unfortunate that we'd have to resort to such acrobatics in Dart. It makes a number of potentially time-saving utilities impractical. As an aside, the answer might benefit from focusing the solution away from the need for a typedef (as now favored by the [style guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-inline-function-types-over-typedefs)).

Comment: You can replace `() => new UserListItem()` with the `UserListItem.new` "tearoff" in recent Dart versions.

Answer (score 15):

#### 2023 answer

In addition to the following code, newer versions of dart allows you  to instantiate without even passing the generic type, and the code becomes much more cleaner:

```
final myClass = MyClass(SomeOtherClass.new);
```

Thanks @AndriiSyrokomskyi for pointing this out.

#### 2022 answer

Just came across this problem and found out that although instantiating using `T()` is still not possible, you can get the constructor of an object easier with `SomeClass.new` in `dart>=2.15`.

So what you could do is:

```
class MyClass<T> {
  final T Function() creator;
  MyClass(this.creator);

  T getGenericInstance() {
    return creator();
  }
}
```

and when using it:

```
final myClass = MyClass<SomeOtherClass>(SomeOtherClass.new)
```

Nothing different but looks cleaner imo.

Comment: This does not work at all.. There is so such things as `.new` 

Comment: @Dinesh Idk what you're saying, literally just works by pasting directly to dartpad.dev

Comment: sorry my bad. Looks there is `.new` but it does not create the instance of the `SomeOtherClass`. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: It's already possible to write shorter: 
`final myClass = MyClass(SomeOtherClass.new)`

Comment: @AndriiSyrokomskyi You're right, thanks for notifying the new language changes. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if this is still useful to anyone. But I have found an easy workaround. In the function you want to initialize the type T, pass an extra argument of type `T Function()`. This function should return an instance of T. Now whenever you want to create object of T, call the function.

```
class foo<T> {
    void foo(T Function() creator) {
        final t = creator();
        // use t
    }
}
```

P.S. inspired by [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33624/patrick-cornelissen)

Answer (score 7):

Here's my work around for this sad limitation

```
class RequestHandler {
  static final _constructors = {
    RequestHandler: () => RequestHandler(),
    RequestHandler2: () => RequestHandler2(),
  };
  static RequestHandler create(Type type) {
    return _constructors[type]();
  }
}

class RequestHandler2 extends RequestHandler {}

class GenericController<T extends RequestHandler> {
  void processRequest() {
    //T t = new T(); // ERROR
    T t = RequestHandler.create(T);
  }
}

test() {
  final controller = GenericController<RequestHandler2>();
  controller.processRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but as far as I know, a type parameter cannot be used to name a constructor in an instance creation expression in Dart.

Answer (score 2):

**Working with FLutter**

```
typedef S ItemCreator<S>();

mixin SharedExtension<T> {

    T getSPData(ItemCreator<T> creator) async {
        return creator();
    }
}

Abc a = sharedObj.getSPData(()=> Abc());
```

P.S. inspired by [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33624/patrick-cornelissen)

Comment: Why is the function async btw?

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28556110/249097), this is the factory I ended up with.

```
class ServiceFactory<T> {
  static final Map<Type, dynamic> _cache = <String, dynamic>{};

  static T getInstance<T>(T Function() creator) {
    String typeName = T.toString();
    return _cache.putIfAbsent(typeName, () => creator());
  }
}
```

Then I would use it like this.

```
final authClient = ServiceFactory.getInstance<AuthenticationClient>(() => AuthenticationClient());
```

**Warning**: Erik made a very good point in the comment below that the same type name can exist in multiple packages and that will cause issues. As much as I dislike to force the user to pass in a string `key` (that way it's the consumer's responsibility to ensuring the uniqueness of the type name), that might be the only way.

Comment: Hi James, note that it is error-prone and unnecessary to transform the `Type` instance to a string (apparently, a comment will not contain code, so please reformat):

/* Library 'lib.dart'. \*/
class C {}

/\* Library 'main.dart'. \*/
import 'lib.dart' as lib;

class C {}

void main() {
  print('${(C).toString()} == ${((lib.C).toString())}');
}

The point is that two different libraries may declare a class with the same name, and they will have the same `toString`, but they are not the same class.

Comment: @ErikErnst You make a very good point and I have edited the answer to include a warning to that effect, thanks!.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, you would just use `Map<Type, dynamic> _cache` and `_cache.putIfAbsent(T, () => creator());`.

Answer (score -1):

simple like that.

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

void main(List<String> args) {
    final a = A<B>();
    final b1 = a.getInstance();
    final b2 = a.getInstance();
    print('${b1.value}|${b1.text}|${b1.hashCode}');
    print('${b2.value}|${b2.text}|${b2.hashCode}');
}

class A<T extends B> {
    static int count = 0;
    T getInstance() {
        return reflectClass(T).newInstance(
        Symbol(''),
        ['Text ${++count}'],
        {Symbol('value'): count},
        ).reflectee;
    }
}

class B {
    final int value;
    final String text;
    B(this.text, {required this.value});
}
```