# Dart generic function for map to object conversion

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to create a generic `parseFromMap()` function that will output a correct object type?

I have multiple data classes that I deserialise from Firebase `DocumentSnapshot`. I'm trying to create an abstract class that the data classes will inherit or implement. All classes should implement a `parseFromMap()` function that will convert the Json into an object. Here's my attempt at the abstract class:

```
abstract class FirebaseConverter<T> {

  FirebaseConverter(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot, String id);

  Map toJson();

  T parseFromMap(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot, String id);
}
```

Next, I want to create a generic function that will parse a DocumentSnapshot into the final object type.

```
  Future<T> getDocumentById(String id) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snap = firebaseRef.doc(id).get();
    return T.parseFromMap(snap.data(), snap.id);
  }
```

Obviously, this is failing because `parseFromMap(snap, snap.id)` is not static. Abstract classes cannot have static functions.

What I've done so far is that I have a specific `Future<SomeSpecificFirebaseObject> getDocumentById()` in each of the specific classes, but this is a lot of code duplication for a basic necessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current `getDocumentById(...)` implementation will fail, because you cannot use a Generic Type as an Instance Type. Generics are not Objects.

Here's one good method I'm referring upon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28556110/6735934

Let's use the `ItemCreator` custom function from there.

tl;dr: You basically create an empty instance of the object where you want your data to be filled on, and return it to the `ItemCreator` function.

---

**Let's begin**

Consider a class `FirebaseSerializer` with a similar method in the question

```
typedef S ItemCreator<S>();

class FirebaseSerializer {
  static T serializeThis<T extends FirebaseConverter>(ItemCreator<T> itemCreator, String id) {
    // (1) Casting your specific object to its base class
    FirebaseConverter item = itemCreator();
    // Your Firebase Specfics
    DocumentSnapshot snap = firebaseRef.doc(id).get();
    // Calling your base class' method, now possible
    return item.parseFromMap(snap, id);
  }
}
```

This method accepts an `ItemCreator` of Type **"T"** which extends `FirebaseConverter`, which would return an instance of `T`.

**Why extend?** For the cast to `FirebaseConverter` to work (*refer (1) in above snippet*)

Now, for an example:

```
class A implements FirebaseConverter {
  @override
  parseFromMap(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot, String id) {
    // TODO ...
  }

  @override
  Map toJson() {
    // TODO ...
  }
}
```

FirebaseSerializer in action!

```
A anInstanceOfA = FirebaseSerializer.serializeThis<A>(() => new A(), "your snap ID");
```

Comment: Note that your `parseFromMap` is still an instance method, so make sure you don't create another instance in it. Just assign the instance members values from the snapshot.

Comment: Excellent answer with all the needed details, thank you! Now, a lot of refactoring to do...